# Path dependent commands in .bashrc

Tags: shell, function

I am looking for a way to simplify the different php versions and also paths of Composer. I found an approach in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53001/412208) that looks very appropriate for me.

I have tried to implement the following for understanding

```
function composer ()
{
    if [ "$PWD" == "/home/vhosts/domainName/httpdocs" ]; then
       /usr/bin/php7.3 lib/composer
    elif [ "$PWD" == "/home/vhosts/domainName2/httpdocs" ]; then
        /usr/bin/php5.6 composer.phar
    else
       composer
    fi;
}
```

This works fine, but I am now looking for a way to transfer the stdin, so that a "composer install" is possible. I hope the question is understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the arguments of the function on to the program you call from the function:

```sh
composer () {
    if [ "$PWD" = "/home/vhosts/domainName/httpdocs" ]; then
       /usr/bin/php7.3 lib/composer "$@"
    elif [ "$PWD" = "/home/vhosts/domainName2/httpdocs" ]; then
        /usr/bin/php5.6 composer.phar "$@"
    else
       command composer "$@"
    fi
}
```

The `"$@"` will expand to the arguments of the function, individually quoted (the double quotes are essential).

Also note that when calling just `composer`, you will have to use `command composer` as you would otherwise call the function recursively.

I have also fixed some minor syntax things to make the function portable.

With this function, doing

```
composer install
```

in `/home/vhosts/domainName/httpdocs` would result in

```
/usr/bin/php7.3 lib/composer install
```

Another variant of the function:

```sh
composer () {
    case $PWD in
        "/home/vhosts/domainName/httpdocs")
            /usr/bin/php7.3 lib/composer "$@"
            ;;
        "/home/vhosts/domainName2/httpdocs")
            /usr/bin/php5.6 composer.phar "$@"
            ;;
        *)
            command composer "$@"
    esac
}
```